# Will using super-glue on the screws of my laptop prevent it from being opened unnoticed?

Tags: physical-access, security-seal

I know someone can break open the case, but what about opening it without leaving evidence?

Are there any seals available for securing your laptop from unauthorized access?

And sealing the sides of the laptop with superglue

Comment: A google search for "laptop security seals" will provide you with a lot of options...

Comment: You have a jumble of questions here. Nailpolish on screws can make it so that any tampering would be noticed. Seals are available for purchase. And what do you want to know about sealing the sides with superglue? Any specific means of opening will depend entirely on the specific laptop you have ...

Comment: I used to have a laptop with an ejectable drive bay. Not something that you would want to glue in. So, with *that laptop* glueing all the seams would not work because they could access the inside through the drive bay.

Comment: If you do plan on using nail polish on the screws, you'd probably want to use something with a non-uniform color (glitter in it or something) so you can take high resolution photos of it to detect whether or not someone just reapplied it on new screws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any seals available for securing your laptop from unauthorized access?

Yes.  Google, or look on Amazon for, "tamper evident stickers".  These stickers will fall apart if removed, making a messy residue that can't be put back in place.  You can put them so they cover screws and along the sides where the laptop comes apart.

[image: Tamper evident sticker example]

> And sealing the sides of the laptop with superglue

That seems a bit more drastic and messier than using stickers, and probably easier to tamper with (re-glue looks just like glue).  I'd just use the stickers.